# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'post'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have been working on implementing WTForms Dynamic Fields. Linked: https://pypi.org/project/WTForms-Dynamic-Fields/

I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'post'`

I understand I am doing something wrong, but I am not entirely sure what, exactly.

My code is:

```
@app.route("/create", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def create():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get('name')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        company = request.form.get('company')
        frequency = request.form.get('frequency')
        datefc = datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date'), "%Y-%m-%d")
        adate = datetime.today()

        if frequency == "Weekly":
            nContactTime = datefc + timedelta(days=7)
        elif frequency == "Monthly":
            nContactTime = datefc + timedelta(days=30)
        elif frequency == "Quarterly":
            nContactTime = datefc + timedelta(days=90)

        people.insert_one({"name": name, "phone": phone, "email": email, "company": company, "frequency": frequency,
                           "parentrecord": current_user.user_json['_id'], "dateadded": adate.strftime("%x"),
                           "datefc": datefc, "nextContact": nContactTime})

        flash('Your record has been entered successfully.')
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        cfv = customfields.find({"_id": current_user.user_json['_id']})

        dynamic = WTFormsDynamicFields()


        for value in cfv:
            print(value['fieldName'] + value['fieldType'])
            if value['fieldType'] == "Text Field":
                dynamic.add_field(value['fieldName'], value['fieldName'], StringField)

        form = dynamic.process(CreateRecord, request.post)

        return render_template('create.html', form=form, auth=current_user.is_authenticated)
```

My form class is:

```
class CreateRecord(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    phone = StringField('Phone')
    email = StringField('Email')
    company = StringField('Company', validators=[DataRequired()])
    frequency = SelectField('Follow-up Frequency',
                            choices=[('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Monthly', 'Monthly'), ('Quarterly', 'Quarterly')])
    date = DateField('First Date To Contact', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Create Record')
```

My goal is to simply have the new fields show up on the rendered page which for testing purposes I have kept the code simple at:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field() }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it as a multi-line code block.

Comment: You didn’t supply the line number or full error, however, reading your code, I found the issue on the second to last line of code before the return. `form = dynamic.process(CreateRecord, request.post)`. I would check the docs, but you might only need to pass the request there or the POST variables, but that isn’t how you access it.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `form = dynamic.process(CreateRecord, request.post)`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular, what do you expect the `request.post` part to mean, and why? Do you understand how this relates to the error message?

Comment: Thanks everyone! You have all identified the right error - I apologize, I should have mentioned I am aware that the error is related to the `request.post`. I am not sure how the code should be written to properly register the new field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to register new fields, you must pass a dictionary containing the fields you'll like to pick out from your `WTFormsDynamicFields` object to be available in your form.

For example, if one wants to add an email field dynamically that is required.
One must provide a `MutableDict` that includes the email field.

**templates/index.html**

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label }} {{ field() }}
{% endfor %}
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from wtforms import Form, TextField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from wtforms_dynamic_fields import WTFormsDynamicFields
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)

class PersonalFile(Form):
    """ A personal file form. """
    first_name = TextField('First name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    last_name = TextField('Last name', validators=[InputRequired()])


class Dict: 
    '''Wrapper klass because iteritems no longer available in Python3.7 dict'''
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self.mapping = ImmutableMultiDict(mapping)

    def iteritems(self):
        return self.mapping.items()
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.mapping, attr) 
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return dict.__iter__(self.mapping)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    dynamic = WTFormsDynamicFields()
    dynamic.add_field('email', 'Email address', TextField)
    dynamic.add_validator('email', InputRequired, message='This field is required')
    dynamic.add_field('subject', 'Subject', TextField)
    post = request.form.copy() # making a mutable dict copy

    # add email in post mapping to declare 
    # that we are going to want this field in the form
    post.add('email', '')
    post = Dict(post) # Wrapping the mutable dict as immutable
    # augumenting form with email field. 
    # Note that if we want to show the subject field,
    # we must add the 'subject' key in the post mapping.
    form = dynamic.process(PersonalFile, post)  
    if request.method == "POST":
        return request.form

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```